# How to download image to local folder using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I need to show picture in ImageView and download that to local folder. Using Picasso library. And when image is loading I want to show ProgressBar of downloading.

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(MYurl.BASE_URL + "/" + getItem(position).getImgThumb())
.into(viewHolder.asanaImg);
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere in your *question*?

Comment: You need to be more specific. If you edit your question to focus on how to download the image you will get better answers.  You can create another question about how to add a progress bar once you have this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try the following picaso callback function and save bitmap to locally folder

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(new Target() {
    @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // cache is now warmed up
    }
    @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
    @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
});
```

Comment: @Роман  please mark as correct if it is use full for you

Comment: Keep in mind that, currently, Picasso holds only WeakReferences to Targets.  You need to hold the Target somewhere yourself.